# Keep object reference when class is deleted?

Tags: python, class, oop, pygame

I have a class `Foo` which is instantiated an indefinite number of times during my program sequence. Like so:

```
def main():
    f = Foo()
    while f.run():
        del f
        f = Foo()
```

with `run()` being a method that runs an decisive condition for keeping the program alive.

Now, my `Foo` class creates on its `__init__` method two objects `a` and `b`:

**Foo class**

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        a = A()
        b = B(a.var)
```

I'm looking for a way to `a` being declared **only at the first `Foo` instantiation** and use that same first-instantiated `a` at the other `Foo` instantiations.

Problem arises because `b` depends on `a`. I thought about a couple solutions - from playing with `__new__` and `__init__` to override `__del__` and global variable as cache - but none of them worked.

**note**: `A` needs to be at the same module as `Foo`

Comment: You might like to consider passing `a` as an argument to the `Foo` constructor that could be reused in your while loop instead of introducing global state.

Comment: I'm sorry, but A should be at the same module as Foo. I forgot to mention that and edited the question.

Comment: `a` and `b` are local variables and the objects, if any, they refer to will automatically be deleted when `F.__init__()` returns—so your question makes little sense, in my opinion.

Comment: Note: `del f` does absolutely nothing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe using a class variable?

```
class Foo:
    a = None
    def __init__(self):
        if not Foo.a:
            Foo.a = A()
        b = B(Foo.a.var)
```

And function B needs to check whether a is None.

Comment: Actually, why would B need to check if A is none? If that were the case, then A would be initialized in the first part of the constructor.

Comment: But if the instance of that class is deleted, shouldn't 'a's content be deleted also?

Comment: @Manitobahhh True! I'm being so stupid, Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @tmvaz No in this case, since 'a' is saved in Foo.__dict__. A hacky way will be to delete it from the the class within the \_\_del\_\_. So whenever an instance is deleted, Foo.a went back to None. But I don't know if it's a good idea.

Comment: @tmvaz No.  Python uses a system called reference counting when determining when to remove objects from memory.  Only when no other object is referencing some object is it deleted.  Since the `A` instance has a reference to it's own attributes, they cannot be deleted before it is.  `Foo` has a reference to the `A` instance, so that will not be destroyed until the program ends (or you `del Foo` and all its instances and everything that has a reference to it)  All `del f` does in your code is remove that reference to the underlying `Foo` object.  It doen't delete everything the object references

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I marked this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you should be able to just make `a` a class variable.

```
class Foo:
    a = A()

    def __init__(self):    
        b = B(Foo.a.var)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid some of your requirements will make `Foo` extremely difficult to test. Instead, I would suggest that you move some of the dependencies from your constructor to a `start` class method that would be responsible for creating the initial `A` instance (at the same module as `Foo`) and then reusing that instance in a `refresh` method.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @classmethod
    def start(cls):
        a = A()
        b = B(a.var)
        return cls(a, b)

    def refresh(self):
        b = B(self.a.var)
        return self.__class__(self.a, b)
```

Then, your `main` function would look something like:

```
def main():
    f = Foo.start()
    while f.run():
        f = f.refresh()
```

By overwriting the `f` variable, you are effectively deleting the reference to the old instance which will eventually be garbage collected.

Comment: I liked the explanation and it helped me understand class methods better. I up-voted either way for your outside-the-box solution, but I find the other answers more cleaner.

Comment: @tmvaz if your `run` method uses `a` or `b`, it will probably be easier to unit test if you can inject those dependencies in the constructor as mocks for example. This will be more difficult with the other answers *without* changing global state which violates test independence. You could probably `mock.patch` your way around this problem but I find this more difficult to read. Clean is good though, so go with what is cleaner for you.